# <font> with Typescript; Property 'font' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I want to use the html's balise font

`<font color="white">I'm in white ...</font>`

Sadly, not so easy with react & tsx :'(

`Property 'font' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.  TS2339`

I don't have any problems with span, h, ...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Font has long since been deprecated. Use styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Phix said, `<font>` is a deprecated tag in HTML, so TS will not include it in its type definitions. This, as well as many other tags, have been deprecated in favor of using CSS to style elements.